# ExtJS6 Create Button UI ion a global Theme

Tags: themes, extjs6

After reading the documentation for theming in ExtJS6 I am thoroughly confused.  All I want to do is create a global UI for a small toolbar button:

```
@include extjs-button-toolbar-small-ui(
   $ui: 'tbbutton',            
   $background-color: #FF000,
)
```

The file is called TBBUTTON.scss but no matter where I place it in the workspace/packages/my-theme/sass folder, I cannot get it to work when I assign `ui:'tbbutton'` to by button config.  Can someone provide me with a clearer path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a button UI definition from an app I'm currently working on:

```
@include extjs-button-small-ui(
        $ui: 'app-iconbutton',
        $background-color: #eeeeee,
        $background-color-focus: #fff,
        $background-color-pressed: #fff,
        $background-color-focus-pressed: #fff,
        $border-color: #fff,
        $border-color-focus: #fff,
        $border-color-pressed: #fff,
        $border-color-focus-pressed: #fff,
        $glyph-color: #4a4a4a,
        $glyph-opacity: 1,
        $color: #4a4a4a
);
```

That code is from an ExtJS 6.0.1 application, and the file is located at: packages/local/THEME_NAME/sass/src/button/Button.scss

The "packages" folder is top-level - the same level as the "app" folder.

Comment: I don't understand it.  Everything is set up exactly like your...even copied your IU definition.  Button just disappears when I assign the ui config to it.

Comment: Are you doing a "sencha app refresh" (or better yet) a "sencha app build -c" after creating your scss file? Is this "disappearing button" behaviour new with my config or were you seeing that before?

Comment: The "sencha app build -c" seemed to do the trick.  Refresh wasn't getting it done for some reason. Thanks for all your help.